# How to generate a random variable from a multivariate normal distribution with huge covariance matrix

Tags: julia, normal-distribution

I would like to generate a random variable from a multivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and huge covariance matrix C in Julia. The size of the covariance matrix C is 100000*100000. What's more, the covariance matrix is positive-semidefinite. I used SVD decomposition(reference:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63817/generate-normally-distributed-random-numbers-with-non-positive-definite-covarian). Even if I have enough memory, the SVD decomposition cannot be implemented due to the huge size of the covariance matrix C. I ran it on High-performance computer for a whole night, then the procedure was killed(I have 1800GB memory while I only used 400 GB when my program was killed). I am just wondering is there another way to do it efficiently in Julia?

The code is below. The SVD decomposition failed due to the huge size of C.

```
using LinearAlgebra
C_svd = svd(Symmetric(C))
Y =  C_svd.U *Diagonal(sqrt.(C_svd.S)) * randn(100000)
```

Comment: Does `C` have any structure (maybe block-diagonal)? Is it full rank, or is your density [degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case)? Also, you could try using `Float32` or even `Float16` if you don't care too much about precision. Also, make sure to parenthesize `C_svd.U * (Diagonal(sqrt.(C_svd.S)) * randn(100000))` to reduce memory usage in that step (so that you always are computing matrix * vector).